# Solving SVM Lagrangian dual

Tags: linear-algebra, lagrange-multiplier

With the Lagrangian dual equal to:

$$-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_{i}\alpha_{j}y_{i}y_{j}x_{i}\cdot x_{j} + \sum_{i}^n \alpha_{i}$$
and
$$w = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_{i}y_{i}x_{i},$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_{i} y_{i} = 0$$

at the optimal values for w and b, is it possible to solve for the alphas by solving the system of equations created by doing the following:

1) Calculating the partial derivatives of the Lagrangian dual with respect to
each alpha, and setting all of these partial derivatives equal to zero.

2) Making use of the fact that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_{i} y_{i} = 0$$
at the optimal solution.

I created a coefficient matrix from the above system of equations and solved for the alphas making used of Gauss-Jordan elimination, however this method only proved to work for certain examples and failed for others.

If this is a poor approach to solving this problem could you please advise me on what I could do to solve the problem without making use of  QP solver.
Thanks very much.